# How to fadein the background image (in n seconds) after the whole website loading completes

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I want to fadeIn the background image of the Website as the website completely loads in the browser using jQuery or anything
here is the CSS i had use

```
body
{
background-image:url('c.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center;
font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#myImage").delay(n * 1000).animate({
opacity: 1
}, 1000);
});
```

It should work. Just make sure the image's original opacity is 0.

**EDIT:**
Here is an example.

[Click here.](http://jsfiddle.net/joeelectricity/GWHFt/)